# Flask: How to display tables in SQLite onto Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have created a table in DB Browser SQLite with real data input. How do I link the SQLite with flask so that the table will be displayed in the html. I want the html part to be displayed exactly the same as DB Browser Sqlite.

This is my app.py

```
@app.route('/viewrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def viewrec():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            use = session['user'].get("name")
            ema = session['user'].get("preferred_username")
            depart = request.form['depart']
            type = request.form['type']
            uploadre = request.form['uploadre']
            amt = request.form['amt']
            description = request.form['description']

            if request.form.get("price"):
                price_checked = "Yes"
            else:
                price_checked = "No"

            conn = sql.connect(db_path)
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM SubmitClaim')


            rows = c.fetchall()
            return render_template("viewpastclaim.html", rows=rows)
    except:
    # for row in rows:
    #     print(row)
    #
    # conn.close()
        return render_template('viewpastclaim.html')
```

This is my viewpastclaim.html
I tried to call the various variables from App.py and use them with rows['Name']

```
<form action="/viewrec"  METHOD="POST" >
<!-- Generate all the claim content -->
<table style=" font-family: arial, sans-serif;
       width: 60%;
       border: 1px solid black;
       margin-left:500px;
       margin-top: 100px;
       text-align: center;
       padding:20px;">

    <tr>
        <th class="type">Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>ClaimType</th>
        <th>UploadReceipt</th>
        <th>ClaimAmount</th>
        <th>checkbox</th>
        <th>ClaimDescription</th>

    </tr>
    {% for rows in SubmitClaim %}
    <tr>
        <td>rows['Name']</td>
        <td>rows['Email']</td>
        <td>rows['Deparment']</td>
        <td>rows['ClaimType']</td>
        <td>rows['UploadReceipt']</td>
        <td>rows['ClaimAmount']</td>
        <td>rows['checkbox']</td>
        <td>rows['ClaimDescription']</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>

<!-- View all the claims -->
 <button type="submit", class="viewall-button" name="save", value="save">View All</button>
</form>
```

If you are able to solve them, please drop a msg below. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that should work. You are giving the info to the template inside of "rows" not inside of "SubmitClaim"

```
    <tr>
        <th class="type">Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>ClaimType</th>
        <th>UploadReceipt</th>
        <th>ClaimAmount</th>
        <th>checkbox</th>
        <th>ClaimDescription</th>

    </tr>
    {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td>row['Name']</td>
        <td>row['Email']</td>
        <td>row['Deparment']</td>
        <td>row['ClaimType']</td>
        <td>row['UploadReceipt']</td>
        <td>row['ClaimAmount']</td>
        <td>row['checkbox']</td>
        <td>row['ClaimDescription']</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

If you still can't get it to work I suggest you use SQL-Alchemy to manage the database. That should make everything easier.

Comment: Hi @Robert, It is still not working. Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your Python variables in {{ }} to show them in HTML format. You also have some errors in your code. You have to replace 'SubmitClaim' with rows since you passed that in your python function. So the correct code would be:

```
{% for row in rows %}
<tr>
    {% for data in row %}
    <td>{{ data }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi user3510806, I am still not able to display the table from SQLite.

Comment: Where do you get the {{data}}?

Comment: By iterating through row, we create a new variable called "data" which will print out the information until the end of the nested for loop.

Comment: The table in the html is still not populating from the database